# Dropdown Menu is showing the first value from my JSON file instead of default text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

***Functionality..***

User is to select the items(read from JSON file) that is displayed in dropdown menu. Dropdown menu should have a default text of "Please select shops..." before the name of the items is shown.

***Issue:***

The default text of "Please select shops..." is missing and the first item is actually shown instead of the default text. I have set the following dropdown `<select>` tag with the following properties:

```
<select id="dropDownShops_1">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
</select>
```

Hence, I would like to ask for assistance: what has gone wrong and how am I to show the "Please Select Shops..." before showing the items that are read from the JSON file?

***CODE:***

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMLz3hbI44R8SlKi4SRs?p=preview) (Somehow the default text is showing but the JSON list is not showing, But in my issue: the JSON list is showing in the drop down but not the default text )

```js
     //get a reference to the select element
    var $select = $("#dropDownShops_1, #dropDownShops_2");

    $(function() {
      /*******************************************************
       *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
       *******************************************************/

      //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
      $.getJSON('ajax/shops.json', function(data) {
        $select.html('');
        console.log("shops: " + data.Shops);
        $.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {
          console.log("value:" + value);
          //iterate over the data and append a select option
          $select.append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
        });
      });

      $("img").on("dragstart", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <!-- DropDown Menu to choose Participating Outlet -->
  <select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>
  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

JSON file:

```
{
 "Shops": [
{
    "ShopName": "7-ven",
    "ShopID": "7-ven123",
    "Shoplocation": "#02-31"
 }, {
    "ShopName": "8Tarstries",
    "ShopID": "8Tarstries123",
    "Shoplocation": "#B2-K4"
 }, {
     "ShopName": "A|hange",
     "ShopID": "A|hange123",
     "Shoplocation": "#01-202"
 }]   
}
```

Comment: your default option is got override by your JSON

Comment: Try  something like below my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some change in your code as follows,

```
$select.append("<option value='' selected disabled>Please Select Shops.. </option>");
 $.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {

  console.log("value:" + value);
  //iterate over the data and append a select option
  $select.append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");

});
```

Comment: You mean to input this line `$select.append("<option value='' selected disabled>Please Select Shops.. </option>");` inside my `$.getJSON(){..}` method and directly above  `$.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {..}
` method?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this from your code

```
$select.html('');
```

```js
// get a reference to the select element
var $select = $("#dropDownShops_1, #dropDownShops_2");


$(function() {

  /*******************************************************
   *FUNCTION CALL TO POPULATE DROPDOWN MENU FROM JSON FILE*
   *******************************************************/

  //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
    var data = { Shops: ['a','b'] }
  
    
    console.log("shops: " + data.Shops);

    $.each(data.Shops, function(key, value) {

      console.log("value:" + value);
      //iterate over the data and append a select option
      $select.append($('<option>',{ value: value, text: value}));

    });
  

  $("img").on("dragstart", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <!-- DropDown Menu to choose Participating Outlet -->
  <select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution

```
$('#dropDownShops_1').append("<option >" + value.ShopName + "</option>");
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/58yMCfo4X7w0NwqS1v0y?p=preview